# Python regex to avoid matching word followed by multiple conditions

Tags: python, regex

I want to match uppercase character words that are in the middle of a sentence, using Python 3. This is my current regex:

```
.+?\b([A-Z]+)\b(?=[^.!?][^ ])
```

So I want to avoid matching words that are followed by this set of characters `[^.!?]` *and* a space. But this expression also matches a word followed by a period and *no* space. What is my mistake?

I.e, at the moment I get the same result using `re.findall()` *with* and *without* a space at the end of the searched string:

```
>>> re.findall(r'.+?\b([A-Z]+)\b(?=[^.!?][^ ])','NO YES YES YES YES NO. ')
['YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES']
>>> re.findall(r'.+?\b([A-Z]+)\b(?=[^.!?][^ ])','NO YES YES YES YES NO.')
['YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex with **negative lookahead**:

```
r'(?!^)\b([A-Z]+)\b(?![.!?] )'
```

`(?!^)` will skip the word at start of sentence.

`(?![.!?] )` will fail the match when words are followed by one of those chars followed by a space.

**Examples:**

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?!^)\b([A-Z]+)\b(?![.!?] )','NO YES YES YES YES NO.')
['YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO']

>>> re.findall(r'(?!^)\b([A-Z]+)\b(?![.!?] )','NO YES YES YES YES NO. ')
['YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(re.findall(r'[^A-Z](.+)[^A-Z]\S+\s*$','NO YES YES YES YES NO. '))

['YES YES YES YES']

print(re.findall(r'[^A-Z](.+)[^A-Z]\S+\s*$','NO YES YES YES YES NO.'))

['YES YES YES YES']
```